# Writing to a .txt file from TextBox when suspending or closing app

Tags: c#, uwp

There is a `TextBox` where user can enter some data. When the app is closed (by clicking the X button on top right of the window), the app needs to take whatever was typed in the `TextBox` and save it to a .txt file before closing the app.

This is my code in `App.xaml.cs` file.

```
private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
    await WriteTextToFile();

    deferral.Complete();
}

private async Task WriteTextToFile()
{
    try
    {
        string text = textBox.Text;
        StorageFile textFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///TextFile1.txt"));
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(textFile, text);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

I am getting a red underline under textBox in the `try` block.

It says,

> The name 'textBox' does not exist in the current context

I'm guessing it's not possible to access the `TextBox` control from `App.xaml.cs` file.

Comment: Try create the repro steps like:Where is your textBox located? The erro is being thrown during compile time or runtime?

Comment: I guess you could implement the `WriteTextToFile()` method in your form by using the `Window_Closing` event, I'm not sure if this event is triggered when you close your application, but give it a try!

Comment: Access levels, depending on your project, aren't understood globally.  Is there any reason you can't just pass the text value to `WriteTextToFile`?  You don't intend to manipulate or change the values in the `textBox`, you just need the data right?

Comment: FWIW, your problem also has nothing to do with writing text to a file upon application exit/close.. so the title of this question is very misleading and confusing.

Comment: I am guessing you want to use this method from any XAML page that has text input you want to save?

Comment: did you try static variables ?

Comment: @gravity the OnSuspending function gets called automatically when the app is closed

Comment: @RafaelDuarte That event is unavailable for UWP apps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write to a .txt file using data from TextBox when UWP app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57336035/write-to-a-txt-file-using-data-from-textbox-when-uwp-app-is-closed)

Comment: The matched folder of  "ms-appx" scheme is app installation folder and it is read only, please try to write file to the app's local [folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in App.xaml.cs

```
    private MainPage mainFrame;
    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
        {
            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
                mainFrame = (MainPage) rootFrame.Content; //*
            }
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
    }

    private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        string text = mainFrame.Main_TextBox.Text;
        string text2 = MainPage.rootPage.Main_TextBox.Text;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("hello.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile , text);
        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

in Main.xaml.cs (TextBox_1 => Name of TextBox in xaml file)

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public TextBox Main_TextBox => TextBox_1; //*
    public static MainPage rootPage; //*
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        if (rootPage == null)
        {
            rootPage = this;
        }
    }

}
```

you can access with rootFrame in App.xaml.cs if textbox in main frame. other way you can create a static variable in your page then you can access with any property

Edit : You can see your file in `C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Packages\{PackageName}\LocalState\hello.txt`

Comment: after assigning the "string test" in the OnSuspending method, I have to write the string to a .txt file as you can see in my original code. I added the code but it's not saving.